# split on delimiter jquery where delimiter is avaialble in Value also

Tags: jquery

I have one string something like

```
orderIDNumber=final &&customerSoldTo=&customerShipTo=&orderStatus=All&productIdType=MMMCATALOG&productId=&poFromDate=&poToDate=
```

where & is delimiter and want to split each part but in  orderIDNumber value i am getting value as "final &" and it is splitting my string on this also can any one please help how to overcome by this problem.

I am trying to split to whole string on & delimiter

pageNo = pageUrl.split("&");

and then trying to set the values to form something like orderIDTypeData = pageNo[1] this.

Comment: so in order number value should be only "final" right?

Comment: You've not shown how you're getting the values from the querystring (which is the source of the problem), however if you do it correctly, as in the question I marked as duplicate, there is no problem: https://jsfiddle.net/nmzk8p9q/

Comment: no Dhara value is "final &"

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan i dont think this is duplicate question can you please have a look once again i have added more info in the question.